# Remove list values from a column of lists based on another list

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame where one column is a column of lists. How would I go about removing all elements within those lists that are also found in another specified list? The original column should be kept in tact while a new column is added to the DataFrame with the designated list elements removed from each row value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Values': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]})

removal_list = ['a', 'b']
```

generates

```
Index   Values
0       ['a', 'b', 'c']
1       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
2       ['a', 'b']
3       ['c']
```

With the desired output being...

```
Index   Values               Cleaned_Values
0       ['a', 'b', 'c']      ['c']
1       ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['c', 'd']
2       ['a', 'b']           []
3       ['c']                ['c']
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Comprehension

```
df.assign(Cleaned_Values=[[x for x in y if x not in removal_list] for y in df.Values])

         Values Cleaned_Values
0     [a, b, c]            [c]
1  [a, b, c, d]         [c, d]
2        [a, b]             []
3           [c]            [c]
```

---

#### `set`

```
df.assign(Cleaned_Values=df.Values.map(set).sub({*removal_list}).map(list))

         Values Cleaned_Values
0     [a, b, c]            [c]
1  [a, b, c, d]         [c, d]
2        [a, b]             []
3           [c]            [c]
```

Same thing but a tad bit quicker because we take care of all of the conversions together.

```
df.assign(Cleaned_Values=df.Values.map(lambda x: [*{*x} - {*removal_list}]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with `explode` (available in pd 0.25+);

```
df['Cleaned_Values'] = (df['Values'].explode()
    .loc[lambda x: ~x.isin(removal_list)]
    .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
         Values Cleaned_Values
0     [a, b, c]            [c]
1  [a, b, c, d]         [c, d]
2        [a, b]            NaN
3           [c]            [c]
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach also may help you.

```
import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Values': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['c']]})

removal_list = ['a', 'b']

 df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply( lambda row: [val for val in row if val != 'a'] )

   df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply( lambda row: [val for val in row if val != 'b'] )
```

and the output is :

```
df
Out[8]: 
 Values
0     [c]
1  [c, d]
2      []
3     [c]
```

Comment: @stream_entry if this answer help you please let me know.